# Is it possible to disassemble an APC Netshelter SX enclosure?

Tags: hardware, rack, apc

I need to move an APC Netshelter SX 48U from one room to another, but the new room is lower than the current one and I cannot install it without disassembling it.

According to APC, these enclosures are not made to be disassembled, but I was wondering if anyone had tried to disassemble one these enclosures ? And if yes, had some tips on how to do it ?

Comment: I don't understand. Will the unit fit at it's full height in the new room?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes it will, but I have to lay it on the side to pass the door and then in the second door I cannot put it back up because the sides are touching the ceiling.